# E2209 Unable to open include file 'queue.h'

Tags: path, c++builder, rad-studio

I'm working with RAD Studio 11 (C++Builder) and trying to compile a project.
I received the following error:

```
E2209 Unable to open include file 'queue.h'
```

With some warnings, which I think might cause this error:

```
[bcc32 Warning] W8123 Path 'c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\vcl' not found - path ignored in option '-I'
[bcc32 Warning] W8123 Path 'c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\atl' not found - path ignored in option '-I'
```

I checked in this location, and there are no files named `atl` or `vcl`, neither in another PC that can compile this project without an error.

I changed the path in *Project->Options->C++ shared options* to where my project is, and also changed the path in *Project->Options->C++ Compiler->directories and conditionals*, but I still receive the same error and warnings.

Did I miss something? How can I fix it?

Comment: "*there are no files named `atl` or `vcl`*" - the warnings are not complaining about missing *files*, but rather missing *folders*. Did you migrate this project from another C++Builder version, by chance?

Comment: Your warnings are referring to studio\21.0\... which is the 10.4 path. You get these warnings when you open a previously created project in a new version (in your case one created in 10.4.x opened in 11. (RAD Studio 11 uses ...studio\22.0\..).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I did, I took it from version 10.4 to 11.0. In addition, I added the folders, and the warnings were disappeared which is good but the error is still there so now I just not sure that there is a connection between the warnings and the error. Why is it a problem that I took a project that was originally compiled in an older version?  Thanks

Comment: @RogerCigol So if I will change the version number it should fix that? Thanks

Comment: No ! The key thing is to remove these old references from the project file. Instead the new project (RAD Studio 11) should refer to ....studio\22.0\.... It is common for problems to arise when migrating from an older version to a newer version (even when only "one notch" further on). Many recommend starting with a new "blank" project and then adding in all the files to the project manually. I usually manage by a bit of manual tweaking of the project file (but my projects are usually based on all the default vcl settings - ie not to complicated).

Comment: @RogerCigol How do I remove the reference? I removed folder 21.0 but it's not enough..Thanks

Comment: @RoyAncri Close the project in the IDE then open up the project file ( *.cbprj ) in a text editor and search for "21.0" and then remove all the paths that include this.

Comment: Looking at the original issue I myself am a little confused. I think queue.h is no longer (or never was) part of the C++ STL. You need to use #include <queue> instead. This will import the declarations of the the STL queue classes with them being in the std:: namespace. eg you can use std::queue<int> MyQueue; to create a queue of type int called MyQueue.

Comment: @RogerCigol I looked for 21.0 in the project file and there weren't paths with 21.0 but I changed <queue.h> to <queue> and it solved this issue. I've received now another error but I'll try to figure it by myself. Thank you very much